# How to implement getch() function of C in Linux?

Tags: c, gcc, getch, conio

In TurboC++, I can use the `getch()` function from `conio.h`. But in Linux, gcc doesn't provide `conio.h`. How can I get the functionality of `getch()`?

Comment: turbo c is dead.Don't use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Equivalent for conio.h getch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474627/linux-equivalent-for-conio-h-getch)

Answer (score 40):

Try this `conio.h` file:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* reads from keypress, doesn't echo */
int getch(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}

/* reads from keypress, echoes */
int getche(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}
```

You can also use the [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library in gcc for some functions similar to `conio.h`.

Comment: Is the `ICANON` flag really required? What is its effect?

Answer (score 7):

If echoing to the screen is not a problem, you could try using `getchar()` from `stdio.h`.

Comment: Echoing to the screen is not the only difference between `getch()` and `getchar()`. `getch()` doesn't wait for a carriage return before being reading from the buffer. E.g. to input 'a' using `getchar()`, you have to type `a[ENTER]`. With `getch()`, you only need type 'a'.

Answer (score 6):

Check out curses:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29

Comment: Agreed, the downvote is unjustified - curses actually provides a `getch()` function.

Comment: Maybe people see that as an overkill

Comment: @Isaac If you're using one part of `conio.h` then you're probably using others. And of you're porting an application that uses `conio.h` heavily, curses is probably the best choice. I think the downvote is more along the lines of the answer looking link-only.

Comment: I downvoted this because it's a link only answer, and, in its current form, it should probably rather be a comment than an answer. While this may actually be a relevant link, I'd upvote, if you'd actually add a paragraph of text directly to your post, about the curses library and why you think it is relevant to solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

`getch()` seems to be included in [curses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29).

Answer (score 1):

According to these solution [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux) you must manually use open source code for getch() and getche() function as described the code is as following .

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  new = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}
```

Just put it before your main method of code

Answer (score 1):

If, for any reasons, you can't use curses, try this:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <termios.h>

/* get a single char from stdin    */
int getch(void)
{
   struct termios oldattr, newattr;
   int ch;
   tcgetattr(0, &oldattr);
   newattr=oldattr;
   newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
   tcsetattr( 0, TCSANOW, &newattr);
   ch=getchar();
   tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldattr);
   return(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, `getch()` is part of the ncurses library. But I wrote a workaround for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410447/why-getch-returns-before-press-any-key) that lets you use getch-like functionality without the rest of the curses baggage.

Answer (score 0):

conio.h is only in Dos,

for linux, use

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

& then

```
-lncurses
```

// In IDE, you have to link it:
for example: codeblocks, Setting -> Compiler -> Linker setting, and add 'ncurses'

Answer (score 0):

`getch()` is in `libcurses`. the use of curses is a bit more complex because it has deep links to the underlying terminal and has to be initialized. a working example for curses `getch()` with initialization of libcurses is in [getchar() returns the same value (27) for up and down arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306463/getchar-returns-the-same-value-27-for-up-and-down-arrow-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getch()` equivalent from [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/):

```
__extern int caca_conio_getch (void)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use system command to control the terminal in linux like this

```
char getch()    {

        char c;

        system("stty raw -echo");

        c = getchar();

        system("stty -raw echo");

        return c;

}
```

This function does not requires the user to press enter and takes input from the user without echoing It requires you to add stdlib.h library to your code

Note : This function is only applicable to UNIX-based OS

Any improvements or pointing out any issues in the code will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: Although technically it works, the "system" and dependency on a utility is just an affront to my senses; see https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `conio.h` on Ubuntu, then follow these steps:-

1. Open terminal
2. `sudo apt-get install git`
3. `git clone https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h.git`
4. `cd conio.h`
5. `sudo mv conio.h /usr/include/`
6. Close your IDE and open again. Done.

If you are in trouble then follow this link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h)