# How to use getch() in a loop (nCurses)

Tags: c, multithreading, ncurses

This is my first time using ncurses library. So, I wanted to use getch() to get a character as it is typed by the user (without pressing return every time). However, when I run this code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

void *userInput() {
char c;

while((c = getch()) != '~') {
    printf("%c\n",c);
}

pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main() {
    cbreak();

    pthread_t threads[4];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, userInput, NULL);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

It printf lots of '?'s without getting any input. Could anyone please help me understand whats wrong?
Thank you.

EDIT: removed dead code.

Comment: @DavidBowling Sorry, I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why getch() returns before press any key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410447/why-getch-returns-before-press-any-key)

Comment: Well, you don't have any `WINDOW *`, not even the `stdscr` which is created by `initscr()` (`getch()` implicitly works on `stdscr`). I'm not sure, but I could well imagine that this is the source of your problem: `getch()` is intended to be used as long as `stdscr` exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three problems with the program:

- `getch` will always return an error because you did not initialize the screen with `initscr` or `newterm`.  Likewise, the `cbreak` call does nothing except return an error.
- even if you initialized the screen, calling `getch` with multiple threads will not work predictably because it is not thread-safe. It's an FAQ: [Why does (fill in the blank) happen when I use two threads?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#multithread)
- the `printf` does something, but mixing stdio (printf) and curses does not work as you'd like.  Use `printw` for curses applications.

As for printing **`?`**, those -1's sent to a terminal which expects UTF-8 would likely decide they're not valid UTF-8 and display the [replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).