# How to use `getch` function of c in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, getch

I had installed `ncurses` library in Linux mint and still I can't use `getch` function in [c](/questions/tagged/c). I am using Linux mint 18.2.

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    char k;
    printf("how are you");

    k = getch();
    printf("%c",k);
}
```

and here is the output:

```
 ram@ram$ gcc-7 test.c -lcurses
 ram@ram$ ./a.out 
 how are you�ram@ram$
```

It does't wait for me to press any key and terminate to quickly. I don't want to install `conio.h` for Linux. How can I use `getch` and `getche` function in Linux? Please don't tell me to make my own function. I am still a noob. Or there must be alternatives.

Comment: `getch()` has only defined behavior after you initialized curses. Google for at least `initscr()` and `endwin()`.

Comment: Btw, you can't mix `stdio` functions with `curses` functions.

Comment: More importantly: Why? what do you want to achieve? From the current problem statement, it does not look like you need ncurses for anything. So?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why getch() returns before press any key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410447/why-getch-returns-before-press-any-key)

Comment: maybe you want to use `getchar()` instead?

Comment: @ChrisTurner No

Comment: @voldimot Please use **bold** only for things that are indeed especially important to your question/answer. And you should probably have a look at the proposed duplicate, it's a very good match of your problem.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Is there any alternative function?

Comment: @voldimot what do you consider "alternative"? There's the C standard function `getchar()` coming somewhat close.

Comment: @FelixPalmen In` getchar` user have to press enter.but I don't want to user to have to press enter.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I think I should build a function.

Comment: @voldimot on Linux, you could probably just use `char k; read(0, &k, 1);` (with `unistd.h` included), but I don't think this is very portable. If you want some terminal control and a guarantee that no buffer gets into your way, using `curses` is probably the best bet, see my answer and the linked duplicate.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Nope. If the terminal is in buffered mode, `read` will not return until ctrl-D or the return key is pressed.

Comment: @JeremyP and that's outside of the control of standard C as well, yes ... I probably shouldn't even have mentioned `read()`. [Here's a better reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a "corrected" version, explaining what's wrong in the comments:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // use the correct type, see https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch
    int k;

    // init curses:
    initscr();

    // in curses, you have to use curses functions for all terminal I/O
    addstr("How are you?");

    k = getch();

    // end curses:
    endwin();

    printf("You entered %c\n", k);

    return 0;
}
```

This still isn't good code, you should at least check whether you got a valid character from `getch()`.

It's also important to note that `getch()` isn't a "function of C". It's part of `curses`, a well-known platform-independent API for console/terminal control, with implementations e.g. for *nix systems (`ncurses`) and Windows (`pdcurses`). It's **not** part of the language C.