# How to handle key presses in C

Tags: c, command-line-interface

I'd like to create a CLI program in C/C++ with the following capability: when user presses a combination of keys, I want to be able to perform some kind of action without waiting for "enter" to be pressed. Just like `ctrl+r` in bash enters reverse search mode. If possible I'd like to stick to standard libraries as much as possible and if I must be platform dependent, I'd like to go POSIX way (I'm working with Linux or macOS).

Comment: Sounds like a job for ncurses

Comment: Bash is open source, you could study its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash terminal uses the [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) you can also use it in your cli programs.

You can use the [`getch()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function to get a character from the keyboard.

[If you set no delay mode](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nodelay) then it does not wait for a newline and should immediately return a character.

And [if you enable no echo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/noecho) then it also won't print the character to the screen.

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413808/how-to-use-getch-function-of-c-in-linux) also provides a neat little example of the `getch()` function.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it will give me exactly what I want.