# How to accept "only characters" or "only digits" from console in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, unix

I am writing a simple Objective - C console app.
I only want to accept digits.
Even if i type a character which is not a digit, it should not be echoed back.
and I should have a character array that has all digits on which i can use atoi().

scanf has formatters but they dont work the way i want.
I know it should be possible. The way it works when u enter passwords in terminal,
they are just accepted but not echoed back.

I just want a variation of it.

Is there some C function that only accepts a character and returns it but doesn't echoes it back on screen ?

Comment: By "scanf has formatters but they dont work the way i want" I guess you mean that the terminal echoes what you write?

Comment: If I were to do it in C on my windows machine, I would do something like this:

`i = getch();`
`if(isnum(i)) putchar(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these link for more info [What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux/7469410#7469410)

you can use getch() but if there is no getch() then you can try the below code.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  new = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}

/* Let's test it out */
int main(void) {
  char c;
  printf("(getche example) please type a letter: ");
  c = getche();
  printf("\nYou typed: %c\n", c);
  printf("(getch example) please type a letter...");
  c = getch();
  printf("\nYou typed: %c\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Getch function gets the characters but does not echo to screen.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about Objective-C (one of the tags in the question), but having a variable named `new` might be a _bad idea™_ if ever it will be ported to C++.

Answer (score 1):

The characters are echoed by the terminal program, not your program. To control the terminal you have to use the [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) functionality.

While the manual page linked to is for Linux, it is standardized for all UNIX variants.

**Edit:** A quick Google-search found this page: http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_4.html#SEC48

Comment: termios is in section 4 of the OS X man pages: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/termios.4.html.   The equivalent to the page you linked is this one: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/tcgetattr.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into using some terminal-I/O library (such as the venerable [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/)), since you need to do terminal-specific things to make the terminal's input "raw", so that you can input one character at a time and decide from your program if the character is to be echoed or not.

Comment: ya, the answer above by niko does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to the beautiful and yet elegantly simple [scanset](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/0080__printf-scanf/Usingascanset.htm).