# Read from STDIN without pressing ENTER

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port, stdin

I need read the stdin in Linux, although my program will receive only messages without new line.

I tried this code, but is not working:

```
int main ( void )
{
    char p_char[48];

    memset( p_char, 0, sizeof(p_char) );
    fcntl( STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, FNDELAY );
    read( STDIN_FILENO, p_char, sizeof(p_char) ); 

}
```

Someone have a suggestion?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr

Comment: refr to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to change the terminal settings so that each character is sent immediately. You can do it by manipulating `termios` (the man page has details).

Essentially it just involves creating two `termios` structures, initialising one with the current settings with `tcgetattr`, copying the struct to the other structure, modifying the buffer setting in it, and then setting the terminal with the new struct with `tcsetattr` (and of course, setting it back when you're done).

Comment: example of using termios http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux