# how to use getchar() function in C?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am trying to use a modified `getchar` function on a linux kernel for an operating system, to get characters from a string given from the terminal, and then print it, but every other time I call it, it seems to basically return an empty string.

kernel level space:

```
int sys_readchar(userptr_t chptr, it *retval) {
    char ch;
    int result;
    ch = getch();
    copyout(&ch, chptr, sizeof(ch));
    *retval=1;
    return 0;
}
```

user level:

```
int getchar(void) {
    char ch;
    int len;
    len = readchar(&ch);
    return (int)(unsigned char)ch;
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the definition of the `readchar()` function?

Comment: I'm assuming that the syntax error on `*retval=1\`` and the missing `;` after `return 0` are not in your code, right?

Comment: additionally one more syntax error in `getchar()` at `len = readchar(&ch):` you puted `':'` instead of `;`

Comment: @Uby: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch

Comment: You define `sys_readchar()` and call `readchar()`; you define `getchar()` and call `getch()`. You define `reslt` and never use it. Is this real code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux

Comment: their in different files, I updated the code.