# C++ Catch Output

Tags: c++

I've got a question about "catching output". `putchar (tolower (VAR));`<- This prints what I just entered via `std::getline (std::cin, VAR);` in lower case letters. I don't want to have this printed. How can I "catch" this output, to be not displayed on command prompt ?

> Example: Input "TeSTIngThis" -> Output: "testingthis"

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < VAR.length (); i++)
{
    char TEMP = VAR[i];
    VAR[i] = putchar (tolower (TEMP));
}
```

Comment: You maybe want to take a look on "pipes"

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - what exactly don't you want printed? If you don't want it to print, why are you using putchar?

Comment: Thanks, just noticed it wasn't what I wanted at this place, haha.

Comment: @zennehoy i second you on that. But i thought `c++` world people like to complicate things. j/k

Comment: One comment, independently of the question: there is an almost universal convention in C++ circles that all caps are reserved for macros (with the possible exception of one character template parameters).  Don't use all caps for variables.

Comment: Not using caps tho. Changed the names of the variables for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want.  Your loop can easily be
rewritten:

```
std::transform(
    var.begin(), var.end(),
    var.begin(),
    []( char ch) { tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ); } )
```

If, like most of us, you do not have C++11, you'll have to
create a functional object for the tolower.  But then, if you
need this once, you'll likely need it again, and it makes sense
to put such a functional object in your toolkit.  (This is true
even if you have C++11:

```
std::transform( var.begin(), var.end(), var.begin(), ToLower() );
```

is even clearer and simpler than the form with the lambda
expression.)

Note to that I've eliminated the undefined behavior you
proposed: you cannot directly call the one argument `tolower`
with a `char` without risking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need to do is use `getch()` or `getche()` in Windows and for Linux, you can use the method described in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux). With this, you can get character inputs from stdin, with or without echo to the stdout.

Comment: I'm using `getch()` for something else ;) Thanks anyway.