# c++ library for developing a command line

Tags: c++, linux, command-line

I'm developing a little utility on c++ in Linux which analyzing big scope of data and return some information about it. You can write some command to interactive command line an it return appropriate data.

First I had only few simple one-word commands. But over time list of commands had grown and some commands acquired params so now I have to look for exactly command spelling in documentation.

So I want to write some advanced command line processor like bash, with auto completing and showing list of possibilities by tab.

Is there any c++ library which can help me in this task?

Comment: Gnu [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) might be the way to go. If you can use boost `program_options` is another option.

Comment: You can extend the `bash` autocomplete with your own autocompletion. http://ifacethoughts.net/2009/04/06/extending-bash-auto-completion/

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but in isn't that I need. I want to implement my own command line like sql clients does. The utility hold in memory large amount of data and return some reports by command that enter inside it. I want command line inside my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [Readline Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/).

You can start from this simple example - [How to use C programming language creating a shell that can implement history capture up arrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824064/how-to-use-c-programming-language-creating-a-shell-that-can-implement-history-ca/28848415#28848415)

Then read this [post at byexamples.com](http://cc.byexamples.com/2008/06/16/gnu-readline-implement-custom-auto-complete/)