# Getting a single character without pressing enter

Tags: c, input, character, fgets, getchar

I'm trying to get a single character input from the user without the user having to press enter. I've tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;

    for (;;) {
        input = getchar();
        printf("%d\n", input);
    }
}
```

But not only does the user need to press enter, it also registers two presses (the input character and the newline character) ie:

```
$ ./tests
a
97
10
c
99
10
```

Since I will always expect exactly one character input from the user, and want this character as either a `char` or an `int`, how can I get the character without waiting for a `\n`.

I also tried using `fgets`, but because I'm in a loop waiting for user input, that just continously executes the `printf` without blocking until input.

My expected output would be:

```
a97
b98
...
```

NB: I'm currently on OSX but I'm happy with a solution that applies to either OSX or Linux.

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: This is possible but we're moving outside of the realm of standard C for that. The way to do this depends on your operating system, so we need to know your operating system to proceed.

Comment: Take a look on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)

Comment: This will probably involve `tcgetattr`/`tcsetattr`.

Comment: You can use [`getch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) form [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATIS)

Answer (score 4):

I have recently needed exactly the same feature and I have implemented it in the following way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char c;

system("/bin/stty raw");
c = tolower(getchar());
system("/bin/stty cooked");
```

Looking at [man stty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html), I think it should work on both Linux and Mac OS X.

**EDIT:** So your program would look like (you would need to add a signal handler to it):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input;

    for (;;) {
        system("/bin/stty raw");
        input = getchar() - '0';
        printf("%d\n", input);
        system("/bin/stty cooked");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My terminal went haywire after this. :(

Comment: @merinoff that's what syntagma was referring to when they said you need a signal handler. Btw in general if your terminal is messed up, enter the `reset` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to press enter only at the end of one command you can use
read (2) from the file descriptor 0.

```
char buff[1025];

int ret = read(0, buff, 1024);
buff[ret] = '\0';
```

Comment: Why a 1K buff for a single character? This also fails when read() returns -1, which it can.

Comment: Yes sorry, so for 1 character, just put a buff at 2 .. and protect if (ret == -1)