# New keyword is used as an identifier

Tags: c++, linux

I am looking for C++ code to get getch() and getche() functions for linux. I briefly looked at the code and I saw that they are using the `new` keyword just like an identifier.

Here is the link : 
[What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)

```
static struct termios old, new;
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
```

Could anyone explain how it is possible? Is it valid C++ code? Thanks.

Comment: That question is tagged as `C`.

Comment: That's C code. It can not be compile successfully as C++ code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is valid C code but it is **not** valid C++.

`new` is a *keyword* in C++ and cannot be used as an variable name.