# In C, how can i get input (integer) without using ENTER?

Tags: c, input, int, scanf

I cant use scanf() because to receive integer input you need to press ENTER (when you are running the program).

Comment: I need answer really fast so please help me with that thing

Comment: BTW i need to get from the users 4 digits in the same row like 4563 end then the program should continue without waiting for the user to press enter (if someone got my question wrong i hope that this comment will help)

Comment: thx guys but finally i thought about using getch with the ascii table XD

Answer (score 0):

Use curses library and use getch function to read a key without pressing enter. This works on linux and i think you can also use it on windows

Comment: Why curses? Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is the only library i know it can do what you want

Comment: I did not ask the question, also what's the advantage over `getchar` from stdio?

Comment: @saeleko `getchar`, just like `scanf`, reads from stdin which is line-buffered by default on most terminals. There's no standard function to change this behaviour, but curses is a good choice for its portability.

Comment: @Quentin ah right, I was aware of scanf being buffered, not getchar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows, then use getch() from conio.h
If you are in Unix/Linux.. you will probably need some terminal/tty adjustments. Check here:

[What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)

Comment: getch() working for integers too?