# Declaring the getch() function

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter your name : ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("your name is %s\n",name);
    getch();
}
```

Why does the DevC++ compiler ask me to declare `getch()`?

Comment: where in your code is the `gets` function? And did you search what `getch` is before asking this?

Comment: Learn [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (at least), not some earlier standard. Read http://stroustrup.com/Programming/ and use a C++11 compliant compiler (e.g. recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/), both being [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) compilers).

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ when the code is entirely C?

Comment: @PeteBecker: Because the code is being compiled by a C++ compiler?  There's a moderate chance that the C compiler wouldn't complain (working in C90 mode), but a C++ compiler must complain.  This is one of those borderline cases where the code is not good C (`void main()` raises hackles in C and C++) or good C++.  The choice of tags is messy.

Answer (score 4):

Because `getch` is not a standardized function. And as such, not in `stdio.h`. On some platforms, it's defined in `conio.h`. Your compiler is complaining because it doesn't see a declaration of `getch` before you use it.

But if you want portability, you should restrict your simple programs to standard functions.

The `stdio.h` equivalent is `getchar`.

I would also like to add that your program is not idiomatic [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). It's more [c](/questions/tagged/c) compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: There's a difference between `getch()` and `getchar()`; the latter requires the return key to be used; `getch()` does not, AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - True. But for the OP's purpose of pausing the program an awaiting the user's "Any Key". I think they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's quite simple...you are trying to use a function but you have not told the compiler what its signature is.  Since both the `getch()` and `getche()` functions are declared in the `conio.h` header, the compiler complains about you not declaring the function. In short you need to add:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

Another thing is that since you said you were using DevC++, there is no need for using the `getch()` function as DevC++ does pause your program right before the console exits.

Answer (score 1):

The "conio.h" header is not present in Linux and Mac, as others have correctly stated. However, you can define your own `getch()` as below:

```c
char getch (void)
{
    /*
        This function requires 
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <termios.h>
        #include <unistd.h>
    */

    fflush(stdout);
    struct termios raw;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &raw);
    struct termios aa = raw;
    aa.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, & aa);

    char ch;
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, & raw);
    return ch;
}
```

This is a very simple implementation that could be helpful; I have checked it on a Mac terminal, so it should work with Linux also. I would appreciate any constructive inputs.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

> getch() is a function and it's header file is `<conio.h>`. So you must include

```
#include <conio.h>
```

> in header file

**For example-**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter your name : ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("your name is %s\n",name);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Your answer adds no different solution to the above problem. Adding the `conio.h` library is already present in others answers. Suggesting to either [edit] or delete the answer.

Answer (score -1):

just include `<conio.h>` and all your problem is sorted.
i.e. `#include<conio.h>`

Comment: This answer duplicates the answer given by [StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica) given three years earlier. The latter being more extensive as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you have problem like 'getch' was not declared in this scope so. I answer this problem
Please save file extension with small c like .c 
eg-add.c  /*this is right way*/
  add.C /*if you save like this than you got error 'getch' was not declared in this scope*/

Comment: what? Please try to give your answer in direct sentences. This is unreadable.

Comment: I also don't see how changing the extension of a (single) source file solves the  compiler/linker problem here.