# C++ : Ask user input without pressing enter using assembly?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, input, g++

I want to create a menu where the user can just press a button and choose from the options on the screen.

I've tried using `getchar()`, `fgets(stdin)`, `gets()`, and even `getch()`.

I've turned to using some inline assembly to get ONE character from stdin.
The code i've used is as follows :

```
char io::u_i() {
    char a;
    __asm__("INT 0x21;"     // Interruption vector for input
            "MOV %1, %0;"   // Move from stdin to a
            : "=r" (a)      // Output variable
            : "r" (stdin)   // Input variable
            : "%1"          // Obfuscated registers
            );
    return a;
}
```

If I've understood well enough how G++ compiles assembly, it should send an interrupt vector (0x21 being the one I found online to ask a key press), then move what is in the register where G++ will take the input (so `stdin` in this case) to the register where G++ will take the output.

I've done a bit of regular assembly before (AT&T syntax), without asking for user input. So this is a bit of a new territory for me. G++ tells me there is an error at this point in the code :

```
sources/io.cpp:7:11: error: invalid operand for instruction
                __asm__("INT 0x21;"     // Interruption vector for input
                        ^
<inline asm>:1:6: note: instantiated into assembly here
        INT 0x21;MOV %rcx, %r8b;
            ^~~~~
sources/io.cpp:7:11: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
                __asm__("INT 0x21;"     // Interruption vector for input
                        ^
<inline asm>:1:11: note: instantiated into assembly here
        INT 0x21;MOV %rcx, %r8b;
                 ^
```

But in my introduction to assembly, there was no need for anything else than `INT 0x21;`, so I don't see what G++ expects from me here. Is there a specific compiler option for inline ASM with AT&T syntax ?

Is my piece of code even going to do what I expect from it ?

P.S. : If it can help you in any way, I am compiling this on macOS Sierra, and here is the output of `g++ --version` :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: In AT&T syntax immediate values like 0x21 require a `$` to be prepended to it. `Int $0x21`. But my bigger concern is that this won't run as a user application under an operating system like Linux or OSX (you seem to be on OSX).. `int $0x21` is normally a DOS interrupt. What environment are you intending to run this program in? Is the operating system development?

Comment: weird, `kbhit()` + `getch()` should've been enough

Comment: Other issues. With inline extended asm all register names have to have a `%%` instead of just `%`. So `%rcx` should be `%%rcx` etc. As well you can move a 64-bit register to an 8 bit register which you are trying to do with `MOV %rcx, %r8b` .

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am going to run this program under an OS X environment, as well as Ubuntu. This will be a CLI application (it's a project for university). And for the MOV instruction, I just assumed I would need to copy what was in stdin to the output variable (as I said, I haven't had a chance to ask for user input in a assembly program, so this is all new to me)

Comment: This won't run under OS/X. It will fault on `int $0x21` because that isn't a supported interrupt on either OSX or Linux.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well is there an equivalent interrupt vector for OS X / Unix ? I've tried all day yesterday to look for one, but haven't found anything.

Comment: You can't use MS-DOS APIs on Mac OS. To remove the need for the user to press enter before your program sees a user's input you need to use `tcsetattr` to change to non-canonical input processing. You don't need to use assembly for this. See https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/tcsetattr  Alternatively you might want to use the curses library which has a simpler interface for this kind of thing.

Comment: If you are looking for an OS/X and Linux solution you may wish to look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7469410/3857942 . It uses `termios` functionality modifying the terminal io settings to create `getch` like functionality.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks. So I don't need any special g++ flags for compiling ? I already use `-std=c++11` for some of my code. Also, does this changes only the input method on terminal ? I wouldn't want to change anything else on the terminal settings without knowing it.

Comment: Ah, g++ will require some modifications but the functionality is still available.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well thanks a lot, this solved my problem ! Adjusted the code in the thread you linked to my problem, and now everything works perfectly ! Will mark as a duplicate of said thread, and solved.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found a solution that doesn't need assembly code.

It s basically a slight tweak of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux/7469410#7469410) thread to make it compile in C++ under the g++ compiler.

Just need to change the name of the variable called `new` in the code to make it compile under g++. Thanks for the help, and I hope this can answer someone else's problems as well.