# want to insert multiple characters to a file in c(single at a time)

Tags: c, gcc

i have been trying to input characters and the character should be put in the file unless users change the value of opt to 'n'.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch,opt='y';
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("myfile.txt","w");
    while(opt=='y' || opt =='Y')
    {   scanf("%c",&ch);
        fputc(ch,fp);
        printf("want to enter more characters(y or n):");
        scanf("%c",&opt);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

So I want to give the inputs until opt value changes to 'n'.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @rsahu i have edited the question

Comment: Why does everyone use `scanf` when [`fgetc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) is a better call?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you type `a` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When you do that, there are two characters in the input stream: `'a'` and `'\n'`. The first `scanf` reads the `'a'` into `ch` and the second `scanf` reads the `'\n'` into `opt`. That is the source of your problem.

You'll have to write code to read and discard the newline character. Here's one way to do it.

```
while(opt=='y' || opt =='Y')
{
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   fputc(ch,fp);

   // Assuming that no more than one characte is entered per line,
   // read the discard the newline.
   fgetc(stdin);

   printf("want to enter more characters(y or n):");
   scanf("%c", &opt);

   // Read and discard the newline again.
   fgetc(stdin);
}
```

---

If you want to be a bit more flexible about your input, you can use:

```
// Make it as large as you need it to be.
#define LINE_LENGTH 200

int main()
{
   char line[LINE_LENGTH];
   FILE *fp;

   fp=fopen("myfile.txt","w");

   // Read a line of text.
   while( fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, stdin) != NULL )
   {
      // Print the line to the output file
      fputs(line, fp);

      printf("want to enter more characters(y or n):");

      // Read the entire line again.
      if( fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, stdin) != NULL )
      {
         // If the entire line is just "n" or "N", break from the loop.
         if ( strcmp(line, "n\n") == 0 || strcmp(line, "N\n") == 0 )
         {
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You assume that user will not enter more than 200 characters at a time(which is practically correct, off course). Also user will not get option to  choose to `exit` after entering each character.

Comment: @cse, with the second suggestion, the user has the option of entering one character at a time too. It offers the flexibility of entering more than one character at a time.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `Windows OS` then you can use following code to read characters without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux) to know about reading characters without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `Linux` plateforms.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char ch,opt='y';
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("myfile.txt","w");
    while(opt=='y' || opt =='Y')
    {
        ch = getch();
        fputc(ch,fp);
        printf("%c\nWant to enter more characters(y or n):", ch);
        opt = getch();
        printf("%c\n", opt);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Note:** You can modify the code if you don't need to print the last entered character. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-getchar-getch-getc-getche/) to know other variants of `getch()` function.