# Detect Ctrl+d if input buffer is not empty using getchar()

Tags: c++, console, getchar

I'm writing a shell-like interpreter using `getchar()` for buffered input.

- If `Enter` is pressed, the interpreter should process the buffer, then prompt for a new line.
- If `Ctrl+d` is pressed, the interpreter should process the buffer, then exit.

The code below runs, but does not fully satisfy the second requirement.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void shell() {
    for (int input;;) {
        // prompt at beginning of line
        std::cout << ">>> "; 
        while ((input = getchar()) != '\n') { 
            // still in current line
            if (input == EOF) {
                // ctrl+d pressed at beginning of line
                return;
            } 
            std::cout << "[" << (char)input << "]";
        }
        // reached end of line
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "before shell" << endl;
    shell();
    cout << "shell has exited" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is `getchar()` only returns `EOF` when the buffer is empty. Pressing `Ctrl+d` mid-line causes `getchar()` to return each buffered character *except* the `EOF` character itself.

**How can I determine if `Ctrl+d` is pressed mid-line?**

I've considered using a timeout. In this method, the interpreter assumes `Ctrl+d` was pressed if `getchar()` halts for too long after returning something other than a line feed. This is not my favorite approach because it requires threading, introduces latency, and the appropriate waiting period is unclear.

Comment: With a normal line there's `\n` at the end. Not so with a line pushed with Ctrl+D.

Comment: @Cheers: How do I determine if a character other than `\n` is at the end of the line, or in the line just hasn't ended yet?

Comment: You can't do this with stdio, you need to use low-level input functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux explains how to read characters without waiting for "Enter" to be pressed

Comment: Are there any cross-platform solutions?

Comment: You could use #ifdef to get a solution working for Windows and Linux

Comment: Cross-platform solutions involve cross-platform libraries, like NCurses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a normal line there's a `'\n'` at the end. Not so with a line pushed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Unix-land shell. So, for example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>     // read

void shell()
{
    char line[256];
    for( bool finished = false; not finished; )
    {
        printf( ">>> " );
        //fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin );

        fflush( stdout );
        const int n_bytes = read( 0, line, sizeof( line ) - 1 );
        line[n_bytes] = '\0';

        char const* p = line;
        finished = true;
        while( char const input = *p++ )
        { 
            if( input == '\n' )
            {
                finished = false;
                break;
            } 
            printf( "[%c]", input );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    printf( "before shell\n" );
    shell();
    printf( "shell has exited\n" );
}
```

Leaving for you to fix the following:

- Handle EOF (empty line pushed).
- Rewrite in terms of C++ iostreams, not C `FILE*` i/o.
- With a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>-pushed input line there's a missing newline in the console output.

Note 1: `read` is generally available also with Windows compilers. However,

Note 2: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for pushing the current line is a Unix-land convention. If you want your program to exhibit that behavior regardless of how it's run or on what system, you'll have to use some portable low level character input library such as ncurses.

Comment: My bad, indeed I was pressing Ctrl D twice. Hm!

Comment: @TaylorNichols Okay, fixed it by using Unix-land `read` OS API function instead of C `fgets`.