# C: Any Alternative way to get each of string element without using conio.h?

Tags: c

**I** am trying to write a program to access the name from user and print each of element and it address but can't figure out what happen to my code. If **Gcc** compiler not support **Conio.h** library so what should i do? Can I write a program without using conio.h library?. 
**Please** explain it

**Here** is my code:

```
//Write a program to find each of string element and it location
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
char name[10];
int i = 0;
printf("Please enter your name: ");
scanf("%s", name);
while(name[i] != '\0'){
    printf("%c is located at %u", name[i], &name[i]);
    i++;
}
getch();

return 0;
}
```

> Output: No such file or directory
>
> complination terminated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)

Comment: First comment out conio.h. Then see which lines give you build errors, and fix them. Looks like it will be very easy in this case.

Comment: You are missing a space between #include and <conio.h>.  I'm not sure if that's your only problem, but fix that and see what happens.

Comment: Please understand that in this program `conio.h` is not needed for accepting the string. `scanf()` is defined in `stdio.h`. In this case, you are using `conio.h` to use `getch()`, which is commonly used to wait till user input before the program terminates.

Comment: I comment out  conio.h but it give me an error in function getch().@hyde

Comment: remove those functions too as they are defined in conio.h

Comment: @Chris Aby Antony  i already remove the conio.h and remove the getch() function but now it gives me an error. It said - format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’

Comment: @suvojit_007 i already remove thoose function which is related to conio.h. But give me an error in %u (unsigned operator).. What should i do now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually display a pointer using the `%p` format specifier. For more information [Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address/9053835#9053835)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char name[10];
  int i = 0;
  printf("Please enter your name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);

  while(name[i] != '\0'){
     printf("%c is located at %p", name[i], &name[i]);
     i++;
}


  return 0;
}
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comment by @David, you should check the return value of `scanf` also.

```
if (scanf ("%9s", name) != 1){ 
   fputs ("error: name invalid or EOF\n", stderr); 
    return 1; }
```

Comment: How about proper indention, protecting the bounds of `name` and checking the return of `scanf` to ensure `name` is a valid string before `printf`? `if (scanf ("%9s", name) != 1) { fputs ("error: name invalid or EOF\n", stderr); return 1; }`

Comment: @suvojit_007 Thanks a lot Brother. Have one more question ! If i want  the  index value of the string element rather than it address what should i need change?

Comment: @TusarHaque use `%d` for index value as they are integer

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for pointing that out. I have added that information.

Comment: @TusarHaque Please close the question, if you don't have any more issues.

Comment: @suvojit_007 %d give an error! ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’. But  I want to use the char data type and get  the output  like first letter located at 0,  2nd at 1.. what should i need to change!

Comment: @TusarHaque use `printf("%c is located at %d with address %p", name[i],i &name[i]);`