# undefined reference to `stdscr' and `wgetch' in using curses.h

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and have this code in `test.cc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <curses.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    initscr();
    printf("hit a key:\n");
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

When I want to compile that, I do like this:

```
$ g++ -lcurses -lncurses -ltinfo test.cc -o test
```

But I get these errors:

```
/tmp/ccTyQ9rR.o: In function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `initscr'
test.cc:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `stdscr'
test.cc:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `wgetch'
test.cc:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `endwin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How I can solve above problem by using `curses.h` and without [writing function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7469410/1043882)?

Comment: You need to put the libraries after your source file in the linker settings