# Getting characters without waiting for enter to be pressed

Tags: c

I want to get a char without having the need to wait for enter to be pressed, I also want it to echo on the screen.
I tried getch() but it won't echo on the screen so it does not work for me.

Comment: you could always print the character yourself on the screen

Comment: "to get a char without having the need to wait for enter to be pressed" in general is not done in C.  Need platform specific functions.  @uMi43,post an example of how code using input and perhaps there is another way.

Comment: You can use `getche()` with MSVC. It's the same as `getch()` but with screen echo.

Comment: that might actually work, thank you very much for the fast replies (:

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What do you mean that it is not done in C? tons of programs work like that.

Comment: **Standard C** will not do that. It needs OS-specific extension.

Comment: @luMi43 weclome to StackOverflow! If you like this resource, as a new user you might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Duplicate if you are using Linux, or perhaps Unix: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getch() or getche(), both functions are in conio.h
The difference is that getche() echo the character and getch() not.
Here more about: https://www.c-lang.thiyagaraaj.com/archive/c-blog/use-of-getch-getche-and-getchar-in-c

Answer (score -1):

Make use of getche() library function. It will echo the character on the screen, no need to press enter.
Before using the getche() function `"#include<conio.h>"` header file in your program.