# How to read a fixed-length string without waiting for further input/newline?

Tags: c, linux, string, io, newline

#### My Problem:

My goal is to read a fixed-length string from the `stdin`, store it into a buffer and then immediately proceed the execution of the following code but neither `fgets()` nor `scanf()` stop to waiting for to get more input, even if the fixed amount of characters to read is fixed -> `scanf("%5s",c);` and `fgets(b,6,stdin);`.

I have written that example to illustrate the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char b[6];
    char c[6];
    
    printf("Enter a string of 5 characters (b):\n");
    fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin);   
    getchar();                    // catch the left newline in stdin because in 
                                  // b was not enough space.
    
    printf("\nEnter a string of 5 characters (c):\n");    
    scanf("%5s", c);
    //getchar();                  // catch the left newline. important if there is any 
                                  // read operation thereafter.
    printf("\nb: %s\n", b);
    printf("c: %s\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
/a.out
Enter a string of 5 characters (b):
hello

Enter a string of 5 characters (c):
world

b: hello
c: world
```

Both, `fgets()` and `scanf()` wait for the newline. As a side note: In case of `scanf()` with format specifier `%s`, any white space would stop the consuming of the directive; In case of `scanf()` with format specifier `%[` and a negated scanset `%[^N]`, the occurence of `N` would stop the consuming.

Either way it is waiting for more input, although specified to read only 5 characters.

How do I read a string without waiting for more input?

---

#### My Research:

I´ve found a way to achieve what I want but it is a pretty large workaround: I could catch each character separately and use a `getch()` derivate for Linux (because I work on Linux and conio.h isn´t a topic here) which are provided in the answers to [What is the equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux) in a `for`-loop and thereafter assign the terminating null character to the last element like f.e.:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, current;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  current = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  current.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  if (echo) {
      current.c_lflag |= ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  } else {
      current.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; /* set no echo mode */
  }
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &current); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    char b[6];
    int c;
    
    printf("Enter a string of 5 characters (b):\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if((c = getch_(1)) == EOF)
        {
            if(ferror(stdin))
            {

            }
            else if(feof(stdin))
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"End of file reached!"); 
            }          
        }
        else
        {
            b[i] = c;
        }
    }

    b[5] = '\0';
    
    printf("\n\n");

    puts(b);

    return 0;
}
```

But this method is a pretty big workaround. Is there a way to achieve that in a simpler way?

Comment: Maybe set `stdin` to unbuffered with [`setvbuf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) (untested)?

Comment: Use a library like ncurses

Comment: Like @pmg indicated, I think this has nothing to do with `scanf()` or `fgets()`. Your input stream `stdin` is commonly set to "line buffered". Both function don't see *any* input before you type a newline. The work-around you found is a kind of complicated way to change the buffering, like pmg proposed much simpler.

Comment: A simply exercise to detect if input is line buffered: Try "X" backspace "Y" Enter.  Does `fgets()` read `"Y\n"` or `"X\bY\n"`?  If input is _line buffered_, `fgets()` gets nothing until the line is complete with its trailing `'\n'`.