# Why do I get an error undefined reference to `getche'?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm using `clang-7` on `16.04.1-Ubuntu LTS`. 
I get this warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'getche' is invalid in C99 
[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

followed by this error:

```
error: undefined reference to 'getche'`
```

What could be wrong?

Here is the link to my code:

https://repl.it/@kallyas/Employees-Record-System

Comment: `getche` is not a standard function I'm aware of , and you don't define it yourself.  what function did you want to call?

Comment: `getche` is a Microsoft-specific function which doesn't exist in your compilation environment.

Comment: ```getche()``` to get a single character entered by the user @DanielFarrell

Comment: It is an extension in Windows MSVC requiring `#include <conio.h>` but MS also deprecate it in favour of `_getche()` to follow the Standard C rules for implementation-specific names. However, the function is still supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getche()` is `<conio.h>` library, therefore it's Windows specific, for alternatives you can look at [What is the equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)