# getting ambigious keypress event in c++

Tags: c++, operating-system

I have written this simple program to detect a key press event. But for all up, down, left, right and esc key its returning 27!! So can not differentiate, which key has pressed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<termios.h>
using namespace std;

static struct termios oldSettings,newSettings;

void initTermios(bool echo)
{
        tcgetattr(0,&oldSettings);
        newSettings=oldSettings;
        newSettings.c_lflag &=~ICANON;
        newSettings.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO;
        tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&newSettings);
}

void resetTermios(void)
{
        tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&oldSettings);
}

char getch(bool echo)
{
        initTermios(echo);
        char c=getchar();
        resetTermios();
        return c;

}

int main()
{
        int i=getch(false);
        cout<<i<<endl;
        return 0;

}
```

what I am suppose to do to remove this ambiguity ??

Comment: You can't read control keys at the console level. You can possibly get it from `"/dev/input/event3"` - I'm not sure if that will interfere with other programs wanting to read keystate, or not.

Comment: linux user ? look at what [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) is implemented. it's a small windows manager that is written in c and that uses key bindings

Comment: possible duplicate of [getchar() returns the same value (27) for up and down arrow keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306463/getchar-returns-the-same-value-27-for-up-and-down-arrow-keys)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I can not read that file. I mean after writing my application I have to port it on beaglebone. And my process will be listening on a serial port. So it could be windows hyper terminal or linux console program or anything. I have to implement it in my process only. Can you suggest me some way to get it done?

Comment: See the above comment. If you are looking to detect keys like `left`, `right`, etc, you need to identify sequences of ESC followed by several other characters. Since your code doesn't do that, then you won't be able to determine the difference.

Comment: now it's working fine .. i did this " int i=getch(false);
 int j=getch(false);
 int k=getch(false);
        cout<<"i="<<i<<" j="<<j<<" k="<<k<<endl;"

but can you tell me why the value is returned in three characters ?