# How can i make getchar() function hold backspace

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==8)       // 8 is ASCII value of backspace
          printf("\\b");
    }
}
```

Now I want to enter backspace and want getchar() function to return ASCII of backspace to c(int variable)

Note- I am not asking about getch function i know that getch command is able to read backspace 
I only want to know whether getchar is able to read backspace or not 
If yes,How?

How to do it please explain me
I am new to C programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check for the "backspace" character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363309/how-to-check-for-the-backspace-character-in-c)

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615045/how-to-make-arrow-keys-and-backspace-work-correctly-when-asking-input-from-user

Comment: @codekaizer i want to know whether getchar() is able to read backspace or not and if yes how? Thanks BTW

Comment: It is probably operating system specific. In many cases, at least on Linux, backspace processing is done in the [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline) layer. Perhaps you should consider using [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to have an *editable* input line

Comment: Read @codekaizer answer above, the link's first "answer" has a good  answer and a bit of explanation.

Comment: @JayPatel -- what is it you are trying to do? Do you just want to catch the backspace so you can provide minimal edit capabilities for your user when entering something like a password in non-canonical mode?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i want getchar() function to catch backspace(the ascii value of backspace(which is 8)) and i want 8 to get stored in c(int variable) so that i can compare c with 8 and if it is true i can print that the user has entered backspace. Thanks BTW

Comment: @TonyB yes the link given by codekaizer has a good explanation and i even came to know about that using getch() function we can easily hold the backspace(ascii code) in any int variable But, i want to know whether getchar() function is capable of getting the ascii of backspace and storing it in an int varibale. Thanks BTW

Comment: Jay, just be aware that on most terminals, the `[Backspace]` sends `127`, `0x7f` the (`del`) key instead of `0x8` (`bs`).

Comment: Who else came here from K&R? 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the stream `stdin` reads from a file, `getchar()` will handle backspace characters (`'\b'` or 8 in ASCII) like any other regular character and return it to the caller.

The reason it does not do that when reading from the console (aka *terminal* or *tty*) is related to the configuration of the console itself. The console is in *cooked* mode by default, so as to handle echo, backspace and line buffering, but also signals such as `SIGINT` sent for <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and many more subtile settings.

The C Standard does not provide any way to change the terminal modes, but POSIX systems have the [stty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) command and the [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) system calls available to C programs to do this.

Once you configure the console in *raw* mode, also set `stdin` to unbuffered mode with `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` so `getchar()` reads each byte from the console as it is typed.

Configuring the console is a complex issue, you may want to read this first: http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Comment: Thanks i got an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your system supports [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) as standardized in POSIX.1-2001, then you can manipulate the standard input terminal to not buffer your input. Consider the following example:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* SIGINT handler */

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    if (!done)
        done = signum;
}

static int install_done(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;
    return 0;
}

/* Reverting terminal back to original settings */

static struct termios  terminal_config;

static void revert_terminal(void)
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &terminal_config);
}


int main(void)
{
    int  c;

    /* Set up INT (Ctrl+C), TERM, and HUP signal handlers. */
    if (install_done(SIGINT) ||
        install_done(SIGTERM) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Make terminal input noncanonical; not line buffered. Also disable echo. */
    if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
        struct termios  config;
        if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &terminal_config) == 0 &&
            tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &config) == 0) {
            config.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
            config.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; /* Blocking input */
            config.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
            tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &config);
            atexit(revert_terminal);
        }
    }

    /* Set standard input unbuffered. */
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("Press Ctrl+C to exit.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    while (!done) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF)
            printf("Read EOF%s\n", ferror(stdin) ? " as an error occurred" : "");
        else
            printf("Read %d = 0x%02x\n", c, (unsigned int)c);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `#define` line tells your C library headers to expose POSIX.1 features for GNU-based systems.

The `done` flag is set whenever an INT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), TERM, or HUP signal is received. (HUP signal is sent if you disconnect from the terminal, for example by closing the terminal window.)

The `terminal_config` structure will contain the original terminal settings, used by `revert_terminal()` registered as an at-exit function, to revert the terminal settings back to the original ones read at program startup.

The function `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` returns 1 if standard input is a terminal. If so, we obtain the current terminal settings, and modify them for non-canonical mode, and ask that each read blocks until at least one character is read. (The  I/O functions tend to get a bit confused if you set `.c_cc[VMIN]=0` and `.c_cc[VTIME]=0`, so that if no input is pending, `fgetc()` returns 0. Typically it looks like an EOF to stdio.h I/O functions.)

Next, we tell the C library to not internally buffer standard input, using `setvbuf()`. Normally, the C library uses an input buffer for standard input, for efficiency. However, for us, it would mean the C library would buffer characters typed, and our program might not see them immediately when typed.

Similarly, standard output is also buffered for efficiency. The C library should flush all complete lines to the actual standard output, but we can use the `fflush(stdout)` call to ensure everything we've written to stdout is flushed to the actual standard output at that point.

In `main()`, we then have a simple loop, that reads keypresses, and prints them in decimal and hexadecimal.

Note that when a signal is delivered, for example the INT signal because you typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the delivery of the signal to our `handle_done()` signal handler interrupts the `fgetc()` call if one is pending. This is why you see `Read EOF` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; if you check `ferror(stdin)` afterwards, you'll see it returns nonzero (which indicates an error occurred). The "error" in this case is `EINTR`, "interrupted by a signal".

Also note that when you press some certain keys, like cursor or function keys, you'll see multiple characters generated, usually beginning with 27 and 91 (decimal; 0x1B 0x5B in hexadecimal; `"\033["` if expressed as a C string literal).  These are usually, but not always, ANSI escape sequences. In general, they are terminal-specific codes that one can obtain via `tigetstr()`, `tigetnum()`, and `tigetflag()` using the [terminfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/term_variables.3x.html) database.

---

A much more portable way to do this, is to use a Curses library; either [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) on most systems, or [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) on Windows machines. Not only do they provide a much easier interface, but it does it in a terminal-specific way, for maximum compatibility across systems.

C programs using the Curses functions can be compiled against any Curses library, so the same C source file can be compiled and run on Linux, Mac, and Windows machines.  However, ncurses does contain quite a few extensions, which may not be provided by other Curses libraries like PDCurses.

Comment: @chqrlie: By accident! :) Fixed now; thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks you have put a lot of effort there to explain.But frankly speaking i am a beginner in c programming so once i gain some more knowledge about c i will try to understand what you are trying to explain.Thank you once again

Comment: @JayPatel: That is absolutely fine; I often write my "answers" as more like background or in-depth explanations to those that have a similar problem, and are interested in it. For you, I'd say my answer simplifies to: Use a curses library. If you use Windows, look [here](https://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm). Otherwise use ncurses, using the package management provided by your operating system; remember to install the ncurses development packages, too. They are often already installed.