# How to stop a QEventLoop in a command line program on a "Return" (/n) keypress?

Tags: c++, qt, command-line-interface, keypress, signals-slots

I was reading around, and I got the impression (correct me if I am wrong) that keypress events work only for gui applications, and the only thing a commandline will detect is a carriage return (`/n`). I have a command line application, and am looking to implement this basic logic:

```
if (programHasError) {
    qDebug() << "Error: Your program has generated an error. Press return to quit";
    QEventLoop haltProgram;
    connect(foo,SIGNAL(pressReturn()), haltProgram, SLOT(quit()));
    haltProgram.exec();
    a.quit(); // quits commandline application.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to start event loop? You can simply request for any button without event loop:   `qDebug() << "Error: Your program has generated an error. Press any key to quit";` `getch();`

Comment: @VladimirBershov `haltProgram.exec();` starts the event loop. I'll look into `getch();` though; Thanks.

Comment: @VladimirBershov I can't figure out the `#include` for getch. `conio.h` doesn't seem to be on my system (Linux)?

Comment: here is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23035044/4149835