# Multi-thread console text animations with std::cout

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to create a function that can animate multiple strings to the console at the same time. By "animate," I mean print a character, wait a specified amount of time, then print the next character, and so on.

This is what I've tried so far:

```cpp
/**
 @param msg        Message to animate
 @param sleep_time Time to wait between each letter
 @param wait       Whether or not to wait for the current thread to join before returning
*/
void animate(const std::string& msg, const unsigned long long sleep_time, const bool wait = true)
{
    const std::atomic<std::chrono::milliseconds> t_sleep_time =
        std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_time);

    std::stringstream msg_strm;
    msg_strm << msg;

    std::thread animate_thread([&msg_strm, &t_sleep_time]() -> void
    {
        char letter;

        while ((letter = msg_strm.get()) != EOF)
        {
            std::cout << letter << std::flush;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(t_sleep_time.load());
        }

        return;
    });

    if (wait)
    {
        animate_thread.join();
    }
    else
    {
        animate_thread.detach();
    }
}
```

This is the driver code for it:

```cpp
int main()
{
    animate("Hello", 500, false);
    std::cout << '\n' << std::endl;
    animate("Welcome", 400, true);
    std::cout << "\n\nEnd" << std::endl;
}
```

And this is the output ("Wecome" animates as sluggishly):

```
Welcome

End
```

What happened to "Hello"? I'm very new to multi-threading, so a detailed explanation would be very much appreciated. Ideally, what I'd like to happen, is to have "Hello" animating on one line and "Welcome" on the next. Is this possible?

Comment: A console has but one cursor. How do you plan for it to jump between the lines?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That's fair haha. Is there a way for two threads to communicate to accomplish this? Also, is there a way to make the cursor jump back and forth, like I would need?

Comment: On another note, if you pass `false` for the `wait` argument then the `animate` function will return while the thread is still running, and that will end the life-time of the `msg_strm` and `t_sleep_time` variables, which means the references to them will become invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good point. I'll change that in my own code to capture by non-atomic value (since there's no writing to the variable).

Comment: There are non-portable ways to move the cursor. I don'k know of any that works seamlessly with iostreams. Research the library called "ncurses".

Comment: FYI: [SO: I/O in concurrent program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48097134/7478597)

Comment: I think you need to pass `msg_strm` by value and not by reference.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but the `iostream` library is really not suited to this sort of application. It does not provide the sort of control you need for this sort of task. You would be much better off using something like the ncurses library. And you do not need to have multiple threads just to do animations. You could just have an event queue and have all screen updates performed by one thread (which is much simpler to manage).

Comment: @gavinb Does ncurses exist for Windows?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson There's [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org) for a start, and you can always just write your own simple layer that uses ANSI escape codes to do console IO. Another option which is Win32 specific is the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 1):

First of all `msg_strm` lives on the stack thus you cannot pass it by value to the thread because it goes out of scope and that is why, most probable `Hello` was not showing.  Also another problem that you have is that you are calling `detach` thus the program might exit before the first thread finish.

To achieve what you are trying to do I suggest to use `ANSI escape codes`.  Therefore the following might not work on all command prompts. Also note that `std::cout` is not thread safe if you print in steps.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> g_lines = 1;

std::thread animate(const std::string& msg, const unsigned long long sleep_time)
{
    // NOTE: `[=]` means capture all variables used by value. Note that globals
    // are not captured.  Also note that capture by value is needed because
    // `msg` can go out-of-scope.
    return std::thread([=] {
        auto line = g_lines++;

        for (size_t column = 1; column <= msg.size(); column++)
        {
            // using `ANSI escape codes` move the cursor to the correct
            // position; \x1B[{line};{column}H

            std::cout << "\x1B[" + std::to_string(line) + ";"
                             + std::to_string(column) + "H" + msg[column - 1];

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_time));
        }
    });
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = animate("Hello", 500);
    auto t2 = animate("Welcome", 400);

    // you need to join all threads else if you call detach, the program might
    // exit before all threads finish.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "\n\nEnd" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more comments to your code? Since this is all pretty new to me, it would go quite a long way to help me understand what you're doing and why.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson hope it is better now.