# C- Why does my code run in an IDE but not a linux environment(silo)?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, ide

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void CharacterScan(int*);

int main(void){
    int* iPtr;
    CharacterScan(&iPtr);


}

void CharacterScan(int* iPtr){
    char ch;
    int asciiValue;
    do{

    printf("Enter any character: \n");
    ch = _getch();
     asciiValue=(int)ch;
        iPtr = (int*)asciiValue;

     printf("ASCII value of character %c is: %d\n",ch,iPtr);
    }while(ch != 27);
    return ;
}
```

As I said, it runs fine in the IDE I am using, but it doesn't run in a Linux environment. I get the following errors:

```
testchar.c: In function ‘main’:
testchar.c:19:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘CharacterScan’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 CharacterScan(&iPtr);
 ^
testchar.c:15:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
void CharacterScan(int*);
  ^
testchar.c: In function ‘CharacterScan’:
testchar.c:30:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     iPtr = (int*)asciiValue;
            ^
/tmp/cceTSMdl.o: In function `CharacterScan':
testchar.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_getch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have never encountered this problem before. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Isn't `_getch()` a Windows-specific function?

Comment: Look at the very first warning your compiler is giving you.

Comment: The error does not seem to make sense to me because, as I mentioned, the pointer appears to be correct in the IDE

Comment: @jakeedwards: It may appear to work, but it's not correct.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Then enable the compiler warnings in your IDE, because it isn't correct.

Comment: `printf("ASCII value of character %c is: %d\n",ch,iPtr);` --> `iPtr` is  a pointer.  Jake, why try to print a pointer incorrectly with `"%d"`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take those error messages one at a time:

```
testchar.c: In function ‘main’:
testchar.c:19:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘CharacterScan’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 CharacterScan(&iPtr);
 ^
testchar.c:15:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
void CharacterScan(int*);
  ^
```

The function is declared to accept an argument of type `int*`, but your are passing the *address* of an `int*`, making it a `int**`. Therefore the type of the argument being passed does not match the type the function is declared to accept. Type mismatch.

```
testchar.c: In function ‘CharacterScan’:
testchar.c:30:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     iPtr = (int*)asciiValue;
            ^
```

`iPtr` is of type `int*`, and `asciiValue` is of type `int`. By casting, you have told the compiler to interpret the bit pattern of `asciiValue` as a pointer to `int`. This is not correct. later, in the `printf`, you then use `iPtr` but format it as `%d`, making the same type error in reverse. It happens to work out, but this is undefined behavior.

```
/tmp/cceTSMdl.o: In function `CharacterScan':
testchar.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_getch'
```

The function `_getch()` is a Windows-specific function that has no equivalent in Linux. You can [implement something like it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276546/10077), but there is no `_getch()` outside of Windows.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you

Comment: "you then use iPtr but format it as %d, making the same type error in reverse. " --> Not quite the reverse.  `iPtr = (int*)asciiValue;` is somewhat OK being a conversion of `int` to a pointer.  `printf("%d\n",Ptr);` has no conversion, just UB of passing a pointer (which may differ in size and passing mechanism) when an `int` is expected.

Comment: I am still confused why the program is running in my IDE if there are so many errors. Any ideas why?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  Anything can happen, including working the way you had expected it to.

Comment: Note that the first two are *warnings*. C is pretty forgiving about type errors, and in the code provided they tend to cancel out. The argument passed to `CharacterScan` isn't really used, exactly. The conversion of `int` to `int*` doesn't hurt anything. Formatting the `int*` with `%d` is undefined behavior, but undefined behavior sometimes means working ok. It's like Forrest Gump's box of chocolates -- ya never know what ya gonna get.