# How can I take user input in C without waiting for a new line?

Tags: c, io, raspberry-pi

I have tried using getch() to no avail. I am using geany ide and gcc compiler on Rasbian linux. I have the ncurses library installed and I am using it.

```
int input(){
int in;
in = getch();
printf("%i", in);
if(in == 'w'){
    return 1;
}
else if(in == 's'){
    return 0;
}
else{
    return 3;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe some help here: [How to implement getch() ... in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276546/10871073)?

Comment: You'll have to set the [kernel] TTY driver into raw mode. See `man termios` Or, look at what `ncurses` does

Comment: Are you talking about raw mode ?
Something like that : https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `getch()` to work, you need to initialize ncurses at the start of your program. This is done by calling at least `initscr()` and to disable line buffering, calling `cbreak()`. From the [cbreak man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cbreak):

> Normally, the tty driver buffers typed characters until a newline or carriage return is typed. The cbreak routine disables line buffering and erase/kill character-processing (interrupt and flow control characters are unaffected), making characters typed by the user immediately available to the program. The nocbreak routine returns the terminal to normal (cooked) mode.
>
> Initially the terminal may or may not be in cbreak mode, as the mode is inherited; therefore, a program should call cbreak or nocbreak explicitly. Most interactive programs using curses set the cbreak mode. Note that cbreak overrides raw.

Or instead or `cbreak()`, another way to disable line buffering is by setting "raw mode" with `raw()`.

For a complete example of reading keys in ncurses, see for instance
https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html

Comment: `initscr();
clear();
noecho();
cbreak();
int input(){
 int in;
 in = getch();
 printf("%i", in);
 if(in == 119){
  return 1;
 }
 else if(in == 115){
  return 0;
 }
 else{
  return 3;
 }
}` This is my code but I get this error when compiling. Motor1.c:22:1: error: conflicting types for ‘initscr’
In file included from Motor1.c:13:
/usr/include/curses.h:667:33: note: previous declaration of ‘initscr’ was here
 extern NCURSES_EXPORT(WINDOW *) initscr (void);    /* implemented */
                                 ^~~~~~~

Comment: @TheChair55 I may be misreading your snippet, but initscr(), etc. need to be called from within your main() function. Writing initscr(); out in the open in the global scope will be interpreted as a redefinition of initscr(), but with int return type, which could explain the "conflicting types" error message. If you still have errors, try building [this "hello world" ncurses example](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html#COMPILECURSES) to test your ncurses installation.